# SQL How to dynamically compare date column with equal operator in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to insert data into a table only when current dateTime1 column is not equal to the existing dateTime1 column in the table. I tried running the query below but it does not return valid result when mydate1 is null in the table.

```
INSERT INTO TableA (id, dateTime1, datetime2)
SELECT 123, mydate1, mydate2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableA 
WHERE id=123 and dateTime1 <> mydate1)
```

Basically I want to insert data into the table only when the date column is not equal to the current date column that we are trying to insert.

Comment: why not using unique constraints?.. and eg `insert ... on conflict`?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COALESCE` to avoid `NULL`s.

So, If you are comparing dates, use constructs like

```
<>  COALESCE ( mydate1, someotherdate )
```

where `someotherdate` is any date which always makes the condition to be false (or true if you need it that way).